# Plotting n-many lines on a ListLinePlot with Epilog information

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I have a graph that I made that has 2 sets of data, and plots these as 2 lines using `LineLinePlot`, does some simple calculations and writes these as an `Epilog` on the plot.

[image]

However, this was done by hand, there's just 2 sets of all the code. Which made me start thinking, how would I go about generalising this to n-many data sets, so I could just enter the stack of data, and the code would produce that line and it's calculations and epilog box (I appreciate I might run into problems with limited space on the graph to put the epilog boxes - I guess they could be put to the right hand side off the graph)

Would it use a loop in some way?

Current 'manual' version for 2 lines included below (minimised where i can):

```
dataSet = {{63, 1.26}, {92, 1.74}, {156, 1.88}, {250, 2.33}, {317, 
    2.69}, {351, 2.85}, {357, 3.42}, {391, 3.43}, {422, 3.44}};
dataSet2 = {{50, 0.55}, {167, 1.6}, {169, 2.47}, {182, 3.2}, {227, 
    3.32}, {232, 3.39}, {262, 3.91}, {281, 1.26}, {310, 1.74}, {374, 
    1.88}, {468, 2.33}, {535, 2.69}, {575, 3.42}, {609, 3.43}, {640, 
    3.44}};

set[1] = Cases[dataSet, {x_, y_} /; x < 423];
set[2] = Cases[dataSet2, {x_, y_} /; x < 263];
set[3] = Cases[dataSet2, {x_, y_} /; x > 264];


avgCurrent = 
 Integrate[
     Interpolation[dataSet, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 
      dataSet[[1, 1]], dataSet[[-1, 1]]}]/(Subtract @@ 
      dataSet[[{-1, 1}, 1]]) // N // SetPrecision[#, 3] &
maxCurrent = MaximalBy[dataSet, Last][[1, 2]];
noPoints = Length[dataSet];
lifeTime = dataSet[[-1, 1]];

avgCurrent2 = 
 Integrate[
     Interpolation[dataSet2, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 
      dataSet2[[1, 1]], dataSet2[[-1, 1]]}]/(Subtract @@ 
      dataSet2[[{-1, 1}, 1]]) // N // SetPrecision[#, 3] &
maxCurrent2 = MaximalBy[dataSet2, Last][[1, 2]];
noPoints2 = Length[dataSet2];
lifeTime2 = dataSet2[[-1, 1]];

ListLinePlot[{set[1], set[2], set[3]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 700}, {0, 6}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 
    AbsoluteThickness[2.5]], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0.8, 0.5, 0.6], AbsoluteThickness[2.5]], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0.8, 0.5, 0.6], AbsoluteThickness[2.5]]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 Epilog -> {{Blue, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataSet]}, {Dashed, 
    Line[{{262, 3.91`}, {281, 1.26`}}]}, {Purple, 
    AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataSet2]}, 
   Inset[Framed[
     Grid[{{Style["Cathode 284 - Drilled", 
         Bold]}, {"Average Current: ", avgCurrent, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime, 
        "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints}}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.40, .85}]], 
   Inset[Framed[
     Grid[{{Style["Cathode 285 - Undrilled", Bold, 
         TextAlignment -> Center]}, {"Average Current: ", avgCurrent2,
         " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent2, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime2, 
        "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints2}}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.80, .85}]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Current Yield: Drilled Iron Cathode vs. Undrilled Iron Cathode", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Iron (Cathode 284 - Drilled)", 
     "Iron (Cathode 285 - Undrilled)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.80, 0.28}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (\[Mu]A)"}, 
 ImageSize -> {550, 550}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Comment: maxCurrent2 is nowhere defined.

Comment: It's defined on this line, I think:
`maxCurrent2 = MaximalBy[dataSet2, Last][[1, 2]];`

Comment: Okay, I've tried using something closer to my actual code, which definitely works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 2;
```

Use indexed variables, e.g., `dataSet[2]` rather than `dataSet2`. This will facilitate mapping of repetitive code.

```
dataSet[1] = {{63, 1.26}, {92, 1.74}, {156, 1.88}, {250, 2.33}, {317, 
    2.69}, {351, 2.85}, {357, 3.42}, {391, 3.43}, {422, 3.44}};
dataSet[2] = {{50, 0.55}, {167, 1.6}, {169, 2.47}, {182, 3.2}, {227, 
    3.32}, {232, 3.39}, {262, 3.91}, {281, 1.26}, {310, 1.74}, {374, 
    1.88}, {468, 2.33}, {535, 2.69}, {575, 3.42}, {609, 3.43}, {640, 3.44}};
```

Automatically detect the break in the data

```
data = Sequence @@@ (Split[#, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &] & /@ (dataSet /@ 
       Range[n]));

Evaluate[set /@ Range[Length@data]] = data;

(avgCurrent[#] =
     SetPrecision[
      Integrate[
        Interpolation[dataSet[#],
          InterpolationOrder -> 1][x],
        {x, dataSet[#][[1, 1]], dataSet[#][[-1, 1]]}]/
       (Subtract @@ dataSet[#][[{-1, 1}, 1]]),
      3]) & /@
  Range[n];

(maxCurrent[#] =
     MaximalBy[dataSet[#], Last][[1, 2]]) & /@ Range[n];
(noPoints[#] =
     Length[dataSet[#]]) & /@ Range[n];
(lifeTime[#] =
     dataSet[#][[-1, 1]]) & /@ Range[n];
```

Plotting,

```
ListLinePlot[data,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 700}, {0, 6}},
 PlotStyle -> (
   Directive[RGBColor[#, 0.5, 0.6],
      AbsoluteThickness[2.5]] & /@
    {0.4, 0.8, 0.8}),
 PlotMarkers -> (Style["●", #, 8] & /@
    {Blue, Purple, Purple}),
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 Epilog -> {
   {Dashed, Line[{Last@set[2], First@set[3]}]},
   Inset[
      Framed[
       Grid[{
         {Style[#[[2]], Bold, TextAlignment -> Center]},
         {"Average Current: ", avgCurrent[#[[1]]], " μA"},
         {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent[#[[1]]], " μA"},
         {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime[#[[1]]], "minutes"},
         {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints[#[[1]]]}}],
       Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5],
      Scaled[{#[[3]], .85}]] & /@ {
     {1, "Cathode 284 - Drilled", 0.4},
     {2, "Cathode 285 - Undrilled", 0.8}}},
 PlotLabel ->
  "Current Yield: Drilled Iron Cathode vs. Undrilled Iron Cathode", 
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{
     "Iron (Cathode 284 - Drilled)",
     "Iron (Cathode 285 - Undrilled)"},
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"],
   {0.8, 0.25}],
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (μA)"},
 ImageSize -> 550,
 InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, so for the most part, it's replace variable# for variable[#]? Thanks for the help :)